# ReCAPTCHA closing Underlying connection

Tags: vb.net, recaptcha

Running my ReCAPTCHA routine in VS2012 (VB.Net), I get the error

> The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive

This code has been working for several weeks, and now this week has decided to give me the above error.

Can somebody give me an idea of what the problem is? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
        Dim recaptchaResponse As String = Request.Form("g-recaptcha-response")
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaResponse) Then
            Dim request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={MySecretKey}&response=" + recaptchaResponse)
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            Dim postData As String = ""

            'get a reference to the request-stream, and write the postData to it
            Using s As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(s)
                    sw.Write(postData)
                End Using
            End Using

            '**This next line of code triggers the error**
            Using s As IO.Stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
                Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(s)
                    'decode jsonData with javascript serializer
                    Dim jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd()
                    If jsonData.IndexOf("{" & vbLf & "  ""success"": true,") > -1 Then
                        Return True
                    Else
                        lblError.Text = jsonData
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Answer (score 7):

The inner exception is:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm at System.New.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle
```

I discovered that the network admin guys decided to implement the ban on TLS 1.0 protocol without telling me.

The fix for this problem is to ensure that ReCAPTCHA communicates via TLS 1.2. This was accomplished with an extra line of code at the top of the routine:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```